# Kähler Potential of Calabi-Yau volume

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, supergravity, calabi-yau, moduli

At tree level, the [Kähler potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold#K.C3.A4hler_potentials) is given by (neglecting complex structure)

$K = -\ln(-\mathrm{i}(\tau - \bar{\tau})) - 2\ln(V_{CY})$

where $V_{CY} = \frac{1}{6} \kappa_{abc}t^at^bt^c$ ia the the two cycle volume.

In some literature this is written in form of Kähler moduli variables as
$V_{CY}=-i(\rho_a - \bar{\rho_a})t^a $ where $\rho = b + i\tau$. $\tau$ here is 4 cycle modulus.

In some other literature this is given as
$V_{CY}=-3i(\rho - \bar{\rho}) $ where $\rho = b + ie^{4u}$. $u$ fixes the volume of Calabi-Yau.

So my question is are these two equivalent? Would the $\rho\bar\rho$ component of the Kähler metric be the same?

Comment: Which literature? Which pages?

Comment: the latter appears in Becker Becker book or Gidding Kachru Polchenski paper(http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105097) and the former appeared in Large Volume scenario paper (hepth - 0502058)

Comment: BBS - pg 498 and BBCQ (hepth-0502058)pg 6 above equation 12 they have given deifnition of $\rho$.