# Why does this allegedly Hermitian Kähler metric have non-zero diagonal terms?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, calabi-yau

In string theory, the Kähler potential of Kähler moduli (e.g. - the volume of a Calabi-Yau manifold) is given by (see, for instance, Becker, Becker, Schwarz: *"String Theory and M Theory"* p. 498)

$$K = -3\log[-\mathrm{i}(\rho-\bar{\rho})] $$

There are addition irrelevant terms (not coupled to $\rho$) which I am neglecting.

The Kähler metric is Hermitian and is given by,

$$G_{a\bar{b}}= \partial_a\bar{\partial_b}K$$

By the definition of a Hermitian metric $G_{\rho \rho}$ should be 0. But for the given potential it isn't. Why?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177153/2451

Comment: Looking at a [Hermitian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) I see no reason why $G_{\rho\rho}$ should be zero, rather, it should be *real*. Why do you claim that it should be zero by definition?

Comment: A hermitian matrix by definition has $G_{aa}$ as 0. See the proof in Nakahara or any complex manifold book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Dolbeault bigrading, the (2,0) and (0,2) components of the [Kähler metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold) $g_{zz}=0$ and $g_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}=0$ do indeed vanish, respectively. In particular, the formula $$g_{z\bar{z}}=\partial_{z}\partial_{\bar{z}}K$$ for the mixed (1,1) components does *not* generalize to the (2,0) and (0,2) components.